# How can I add a value to a column after table comparison through query on MS Access

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2016

as I mentioned on the title of this post I'm searching a method to write on a table field of Access through a query, the value "DELETED" or "INSERTED" based to a comparison of 2 similar tables.
This is my query:

```
SELECT A.[Codice T_CAD], A.[Codice Comp], A.Quantita, A.Desc_ITA, IIf(IsNull(B.[Codice ProJ]),"DELETED","INSERTED")
FROM [Tabella Ponte Distinte 4_0] A
LEFT JOIN qdfImport40RecuperaDistinteComponenti B ON (A.[Codice Comp] = B.[Codice ProJ]) AND (A.[Codice T_CAD] = B.Codice_SEZ)
WHERE (((B.[Codice ProJ]) Is Null));
```

The query returns 3 records:

```
Codice T_CAD      Codice Comp      Quantita Desc_ITA                  Status
TNAA9012AA03115   ARR0004267007           1 PIANO 50X113              DELETED
TNAA9012AA03115   ARR0004269007           1 PIANO 66X113              DELETED
TNAA9012AA03115   11001317                1 Esagono betulla 9 mm      DELETED
```

instead of:

```
Codice T_CAD      Codice Comp      Quantita Desc_ITA                 Status
TNAA9012AA03115   ARR0004267007           1 PIANO 50X113             INSERTED
TNAA9012AA03115   ARR0004269007           1 PIANO 66X113             INSERTED
TNAA9012AA03115   11001317                1 Esagono betulla 9 mm     DELETED
```

beacuse the table A has 2 new records and 1 deleted compared to the second query.
How can I manage the status of record affected by query returning the corresponding value?

EDIT: these are the structure of tables:

qdfImport40RecuperaDistinteComponenti:

```
Codice_SEZ      Codice ProJ     Desc_ITA            Quantita
TNAA9012AA03115 ARR0004266007   PIANO 42X113 MDF           1
TNAA9012AA03115 515454          Tasca in plexiglas         1
TNAA9012AA03115 ARR0003671007   TELAIO SCALETTA            1
TNAA9012AA03115 ARR0004268007   PIANO 58X113 MDF           1
TNAA9012AA03115 515453          Tasca in plexiglas         1
TNAA9012AA03115 ARR0003997007   PORTA PREZZO TAVOLO        1
```

[Tabella Ponte Distinte 4_0]

```
Codice_SEZ      Codice ProJ     Desc_ITA            Quantita
TNAA9012AA03115 ARR0004266007   PIANO 42X113 MDF           1
TNAA9012AA03115 515454          Tasca in plexiglas         1
TNAA9012AA03115 ARR0003671007   TELAIO SCALETTA            1
TNAA9012AA03115 ARR0004268007   PIANO 58X113 MDF           1
TNAA9012AA03115 515453          Tasca in plexiglas         1
TNAA9012AA03115 ARR0003997007   PORTA PREZZO TAVOLO        1
TNAA9012AA03115 ARR0004269007   PIANO 66X113 MDF SP25      1 (this record must be marked as "DELETED" because there is no more on previous query)
TNAA9012AA03115 ARR0004267007   PIANO 50X113 MDF SP25      1 (this record must be marked as "DELETED" because there is no more on previous query)
TNAA9012AA03115 11001317        Esagono betulla 9 mm       1 (this record must be marked as "INSERTED" because it is a new record).
```

Comment: What identifies `Esagono betulla 9 mm` as the new record?  It's the last entry in the table, but the order of records in a database doesn't matter.

Comment: For each record found in the second table that there is not in the "qdfImport40RecuperaDistinteComponenti" query, my initial query has to mark as "INSERTED", if the record doesn't match in the second table so the query has to mark it as "DELETED".

Comment: Your `JOIN` fields in query do not align to tables. They should be the same in both.

Comment: So, each record that is in `Tabella Ponte Distinte 4_0`, but not in `qdfImport40RecuperaDistinteComponenti` is marked as _INSERTED_. Each record that isn't in `Tabella Ponte Distinte 4_0`, and is in `qdfImport40RecuperaDistinteComponenti` is marked as _DELETED_?  That sounds a bit weird... might just be me though.

Comment: Head table is [Tabella Ponte Distinte 4_0]. The query qdfImport40RecuperaDistinteComponenti is older than head table and all new records that are in head table must to be marked (from the initial query of this post) as "INSERTED" and all records that are no longer in the head table must to be marked as "DELETED".

Comment: So, I would like to understand which records no longer exist and which records are new as a result of the comparison of the head table with the qdfImport40RecuperaDistinteComponenti query..